# Create Poll contents type

Tags: 7, entities, polls

needed to create some content types that have a field that creates a vote, as a poll.
Have you tested the modules and Advanced Poll Pollfield but as yet there is not a production version-these contain some errors.

Someone has a solution in order to implement content types with polls?